# NLog layout renderers don't seem to work in configuration

Tags: c#, nlog

Using ASP.NET v4.7.2, in `nlog.config` I have this target:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="{gdc:item=logFileName}" layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"/>
```

In `Global.asax.cs:Application_Start` I have this:

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("logFileName", @"c:\\Temp\\nlog-all-${shortdate}.txt");
```

And just for good measure:

```
LogManager.Configuration = LogManager.Configuration.Reload();
```

Putting a breakpoint on the line immediately following, and digging into the `LogManager.Configuration` properties, I find that the `File` log target has this for its `FileName` property:

```
FileName="{gdc:item=logFileName}"
```

When I write to the logger, it creates a file in the application root called--you guessed it--`{gdc:item=logFileName}`.

In the Command window, at a breakpoint immediately following the GDC set, I executed the null log action recommended by Mr Kristensen in his answer:

```
((NLog.Targets.FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets[1]).FileName.Render(NLog.LogEventInfo.CreateNullEvent())
```

The result was `{gdc:item=logFileName}`

In other words, it looks like the GDC layout renderer isn't working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Updated my answer about remembering to correct `{gdc}` to `${gdc}`

Answer (score 1):

Works as intended. FileName-property is a NLog Layout. Means it can resolve its value dynamically depending on LogEvent. When looking at the FileName-property using the debugger then you are not providing a LogEvent.

Try doing this in a debug-watch (Remember to correct `{gdc}` to `${gdc}`)

```
fileTarget.FileName.Render(NLog.LogEventInfo.CreateNullEvent());
```

NLog Layout engine allows you to capture all kind of context-information, without adding it to the actual LogEvent. But can also extract [context from the LogEvent](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context).

See also https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers and https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layouts

But `${gdc}` is intended for global-variables and not for embedding layout-renderers. Instead you could configure like this:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${gdc:item=logDirectory}/nlog-all-${shortdate}.txt" ... />
```

And assign the GDC variable like this:

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("logDirectory", @"c:\\Temp");
```

If you absolutely need layout-renderer logic embedded in the value, then you should consider using [${var}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer) instead of `${gdc}`.